# Lipschitz maps cannot increase the volume of a Borel set by a factor greater than $k^n$.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, riemannian-geometry, volume, lipschitz-functions, geometric-inequalities

Let $(M,\,g,\,d,\,vol_g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with metric $g$, geodesic distance $d$ and volume form measure $vol_g = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}\cdot m$ ($m$ = Lebesgue measure) and a Lipschitz map $f:K\to f(K) \subseteq M$, with Lipschitz constant $k$, where $K\subseteq M$ is compact. What I would like to show is that for any Borel set $A\subseteq K$ one has $$vol_g(f(A)) \leq Ck^n vol_g(A)$$ where $C>0$ is a constant (in my source of the problem the author claims that $C=1$, but for my purpose it suffices to be any constant).

What I've managed so far is to use the regularity of measure and the well-known Vitali's Covering Lemma to reduce the problem in showing that for every ball $B_x(r)$, where $x\in K$ and $r$ is as small as we would want it to be, we must have $$vol_g(f(B_x(r))) \leq C k^n vol_g(B_x(r)).$$

Using the Lipschitz continuity we can get to $$vol_g(f(B_x(r))) \leq k^n vol_g(B_{f(x)}(r))$$ and this is where I'm stuck. I'm thinking of using Bishop-Gromov and symbolic manipulation but, firstly, I don't know anything about a lower Ricci bound and, secondly, even if I did it seems like an overkill, since the author describes the above problem exactly as in my title and gives not even a hint about its proof.

How should I move on?

Comment: You can use the fact that Lipschitz maps are absolutely continuous and differentiable a.e., so you can compute volumes using integration. By the way, your last inequality should have $B_x(r)$ on both sides, not $B_{f(x)}(r)$.

Comment: My last inequality should, indeed, have $B_x(r)$ but that's what I'm trying to show! I put $B_{f(x)}(r)$, since that's what can I show, using only the Lipschitz continuity! I didn't completely understand your argument!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. I've already shown that it suffices to prove the second inequality in order to prove the first, though regularity and Vital, but I can't prove the second one! The third one is just my progress in proving it! Hope this helps!

Comment: I suggest you update your post by adding the proof of that inequality, your mistake is there (if you do it right, you will get center at $x$, not at $f(x)$). Also, you should spell out your definition of volume.

Comment: About the inequality: Fix $x\in K$. For every $z\in B_x(r)$ one has $d(f(x),\,f(z)) \leq kd(x,\,z) < kr$ so that $f(B_x(r)) \subseteq B_{f(x)}(kr) \implies vol_g(f(B_x(r)) \leq k^n vol_g(B_{f(x)}(r))$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: If your metric is continuous, then $\ \sqrt{\det\left(g_{ij}\right)}\ $ will be bounded above and below by positive constants $\ k_u, k_l\ $ on $\ K\cup f(K)\ $.   Therefore
\begin{align}
 vol_g\left(B_{f(x)}(r)\right)&\le k_um\left(B_{f(x)}(r)\right)\\&=k_u m\left(B_x(r)\right)\\&\le\frac{k_u}{k_l}vol_g \left(B_x(r)\right)
\end{align}

Comment: @lonzaleggiera elegant and simple! Thank you very much. Only one question, though! What tells us that $k_l$ has to be non-zero?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Is it the fact that $(g_{ij})$ is always invertible? If yes, why is that?

Comment: Yes.  If $\ g_{ij}\ $ is invertible and continuous, $\ \sqrt{\det\left(g_{ij}\right)}\ $ will be positive and continuous, and since $\ K\cup f(K)\ $ is compact, it must achieve its lower bound on that set, which must therefore be positive.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera sorry, I meant why $(g_{ij})$ is $\textit{always}$ invertible!? Additionally, I would like to add something to the above. Since $g_{ij}$ depends on a chart, in order to have uniform bounds, we must take finite normal neighbourhoods that cover our set, right?

Comment: @Sotiris Simos My understanding is that  $\ \left(g_{ij}\right)\ $
is *positive definite* for a [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold), in which case it must be invertible (and have a positive determinant). If that weren't the case, then I suspect your conclusion wouldn't be true.

Comment: Thank you very much!